# Popup.html interage com o document?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Sou iniciante em fazer extensões para o Chrome e gostaria de fazer uma Extension com o popup que contenha alguns botões que completem campos de texto da página carregada na Tab ativa. No momento, consegui fazer apenas o próprio botão da extensão completar esses campos. É possível fazer por popup?